# To or till a certain extent

Tags: prepositions, phrases

Is the sentence "till a certain extent" correct? If not why?

"To a certain extent" is very common. Also please suggest why to prefer "to" over "till".

Comment: *To...* is idiomatic. *'til (until)...* is not. You would use the first and not the second. It's just not a matter of preference.

Answer (score 1):

No, "till a certain extent" is incorrect. "Till" is a shortened version of "until", which does not collocate with "extent", as shown in [this Ngram look-up](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+the+extent%2Cuntil+the+extent%2Ctill+the+extent&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20the%20extent%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cuntil%20the%20extent%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctill%20the%20extent%3B%2Cc0).

"...***to** a certain extent*..." is correct because "to" correlates with "extent".